# Mocha - Multiple async calls inside one test leads to timeout error

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, integration-testing

So I have a nodeJS backend and I'm trying to add integration tests.

The problem is, it is always exceeding the 2seconds timeout. Mocha documentation is telling me to call "done()" at the callback of promise or return the promise.

I cannot use both because it will throw another error. I have multiple async calls in a single test so I don't know where to call done().

Manually setting the timeout time is not an option for me, I don't like it and it is not an elegant solution.

```
it('should return a working presigned upload URL', async () => {
    let objectFromS3;        

    // get the presigned url, try if we can upload to S3 using this url
    const uploadUrl = await module.getPresignedUploadUrl();

    // upload a sample file using the uploadUrl
    await axios.put(uploadUrl, sampleVideoFile);

    // Directly get the object from S3 to check if its really uploaded there
    // s3Params contains the Bucket and Key(file name)
    objectFromS3 = await s3.getObject(s3Params).promise();

    expect(objectFromS3).to.not.undefined;

    // Delete the uploaded object (I can put this inside afterEach)
    await s3.deleteObject(s3Params).promise();
})
```

As you can see I have multiple async calls in a single test so I don't know which promise to return or in where to use done();

I tried passing `done` in the parameter and used `done()` at the last line and it results to:

```
Error: Resolution method is overspecified. Specify a callback *or* return a Promise; not both.
```

Comment: Try removing the `s3.DeleteObject` line and put the clean up in an `after` hook. If that doesn't work, try changing from using a arrow function to `async function() {}` in your `it()` declaration.

Comment: try to manually set a timeout if the steps exceed 2sec time. And follow the above suggestion. Don't use arrow functions!

Answer (score 0):

mocha can be finachy but have you tried calling done() at the end of your test.

you will need to pass done in as a parameter aswell i.e async function(done){
some code 
}

Comment: Of course yes. That was the thing I tried. It results to 

"Error: Resolution method is overspecified. Specify a callback *or* return a Promise; not both."

That is what I'm referring to "it will throw another error"

Comment: My only other suggestion is to console.log out and check your responses. otherwise try the thing you don,t want to do and extended your time out. unless you wanted to have some sought of a callback scenario with each wrapped in a function unless they have built in callback options. good luck !

Comment: Hmmm, ok. I have a console.log(objectFromS3) and it contains the file. The expectations passed but still an error because of the 2000ms timeout issue